# Java Garbage Collection, Class Based Tenuring

Tags: java, garbage-collection, latency

I have been playing with the parameters of the Java Garbage Collector, and I'm seeing expensive and frequent minor garbage collections as the eden/survivor space fills up. This is due to me allocating a pool of very large objects. These objects I know are "permament", in that they are reused but will never be GCed. I'm therefore trying to find a way to "automatically" place objects of these types in the old generation rather than in the new one.

I'm currently getting around this issue by allocating a very large new generation (to avoid the very frequent minor GCs), unfortunately, this means that each individual collection is more expensive.

I would like to be able to specify, per-class, a tenure rate, and set it as very low for the specific classes of objects which I know will never get GCed (and which are very very large)
(in his case, it's about

My application is highly latency sensitive.

My current set up is using CMS with a min/max heap size of 48.

Is this possible? I have searched through every possible JVM flag and can't find anything to that effect, and cannot see a way to do it with a custom class loader.

Comment: If you have a large number of "permanent" objects, it is worth evaluating off-heap storage. Be advised, however, that is not a standard Java solution. 

Implementation example: https://github.com/OpenHFT/HugeCollections
Overall article: http://www.infoq.com/articles/Open-JDK-and-HashMap-Off-Heap

Comment: Doing your own object pooling is nearly always a bad idea.  However, if you really are set on creating a large pool of objects, look at the off-heap technologies that will allow you to side step the garbage collector

Comment: Being able to give "hints" to GC based on an object's class is actually a good idea.  I'm pretty sure GC does this already for some system classes, but I've never heard it suggested to enable this for user classes.

Comment: (Actually, doing it based on class loader might possibly be better in that the authorization could be controlled and you wouldn't have to enumerate all the classes.  But it would also introduce some complications since you wouldn't be able to keep related classes together.  (Unless one added an `@` option or marker interface for the selected classes.)

Comment: Re "specify, per-class, a tenure rate," in my experience "large objects" are almost always arrays since few classes have more than a few dozen fields at most, so though some non-array objects pin large arrays in memory the actual space is taken up by the arrays, and most programs have both large and small arrays of any particular element type.  Are you dealing with concrete classes with thousands of fields?

Comment: No you're right, these are indeed classes containing a large array. I was hoping for some way to specify that the wrapper class, and the underlying array would be directly allocated in old.

Comment: @user1018513, That would seem to require malloc to introspect on the Java stack to infer ownership based on the caller.  Maybe there's configuration options that enable that, but I doubt it and think babernathy's pointers might be your best bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering Hotspot, there is no such flag that would allow you to allocate certain Class instances directly in the OldGen.

If the pool is really reused and "permanent", you should be getting frequent minor gcs only during the pool allocation. You need to run your application for a longer period of time and see if the pool was indeed tenured. After that, you should not be seeing any minor GC caused by the pool usage.